# How can I work out this part of a class diagram?

Tags: c#, uml, class-diagram

For school homework I'm supposed to work out a class diagram in C#. Everything went smoothly, but I'm struggling with the constructor for the Track part.

So I think I have to convert a SectionTypes -> Section to put it in the LinkedList, but this doesn't seem logical to me, or am I missing something? Should I convert it in any way or is my overall code for Section wrong?

Here is the class diagram

[image: The class diagram]

Here is the part of Section:

```
namespace Model
{
    public enum SectionTypes { Straight, LeftCorner, RightCorner, StartGrid, Finish }
    internal class Section
    {
        public SectionTypes SectionType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally here is where I'm trying to make the constructor, Track:

```
namespace Model
{
    internal class Track
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public LinkedList<Section> Sections { get; set; }

        public Track(string name, SectionTypes[] sections)
        {
            Name = name;
            // set Sections here
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I get is [CS1503](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1503?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1503)), when I try to add anything to Sections in the front, which means the types aren't the same.

Thanks for reading, and thank you for helping in advance!

Comment: A couple of things.  1) It was nice to like the error code to it's help page.  It would be even nicer to paste in the entire message (that way we'd know what TypeA and TypeB are in the message (there are literally thousands of messages, I don't know them all).  2) show us where this message occurred in your code

Comment: Hey @Flydog57 I tried to add the first array element to the start of the linkedlist:

            Sections.AddFirst(sections[0]);

And got:

CS1503:Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Model.SectionTypes' to 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode<Model.Section>'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I did.  By the way, I renamed the `SectionTypes` enumeration to `SectionType` (that way, it reads `SectionType.Finish`, not `SectionTypes.Finish`).

First I created the enum the same as you:

```
public enum SectionType
{
    Straight,
    LeftCorner,
    RightCorner,
    StartGrid,
    Finish,
}
```

and the `Section` class pretty much the same way:

```
public class Section
{
    public SectionType SectionType { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure why the class diagram is laid out the way it is, but you need to translate a `SectionType` to a `Section` in order to get it to work.  That's pretty easy; a `Section` is a pretty stupid/simple wrapper around a single `SectionType`.  So, things end up looking like:

```
public class Track
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public LinkedList<Section> Sections { get; set; } = new LinkedList<Section>();

    public Track(string name, SectionType[] sections)
    {
        Name = name;
        foreach (var section in sections)
        {
            Sections.AddLast(new Section { SectionType = section });
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I construct the `Sections` `LinkedList`.  It can either be done the way I show, or it could be done in the constructor.  But, the magic is to convert the incoming `SectionType[] sections` into a collection of `Section` type.  I'm sure that there is a way to do this with LINQ (though I don't have a lot of experience with the LinkedList collection).  But, doing it explicitly like this makes it more clear.

Comment: Super helpful, and now I understnad what I did wrong. Thank you very very much. Have a great day!

Comment: Oh, one thing you might consider... Consider removing the _Setters_ on both the `Name` and the `Sections` properties.  That way, you create and set them at construction time, and your clients can't set them afterwards.  This won't work if you want to make your class serializable (serializers like to be able to get and set stuff).  Similarly, you could create a constructor in the `Section` class that takes a `SectionType` and remove the _setter_ for the `SectionType` property.  It doesn't match the class diagram, but it makes good sense